# example of matrices

Tags: matrices

Show that $\forall n,k\geq 2$, there are invertible non diagonal matrices $\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that  $A_{1}^{-1}+A_{2}^{-1}+\cdots +A_{k}^{-1}=(A_{1}+A_{2}+\cdots +A_{k})^{-1}$.

I only need one example of $2 \times 2$ matrix with this property, because then I can solve it easily using a block matrix.

Comment: Please find a title that describes your question. "example of matrices" is essentially meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

You wish to have

$$A^{-1}+B^{-1}=(A+B)^{-1}$$ the same as 
$$(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=I+AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}+I=I$$ or 
$$AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}=-I$$

Let $C=AB^{-1}$ then the equation becomes

$$C+C^{-1}=-I$$ multiplying and rearranging, 
$$C^2+C+I=0$$

Now the characteristic polynomial of $C=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$
is $$x^2-tr(C)x+\det(C)=0$$
So you have

$$a+d=-1$$ and 
$$ad-bc=1$$

For example $$C=\begin{pmatrix} 1&-3\\1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$
Now chose ANY invertible $B$ and let $A=CB$.

For those of us who are incapable of taking an idea and using it, who need everything spelled out for them, here is how to generalise. Given $A$ and $B$ as above, let $X=A+B$ then $X^{-1}=A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ and so to get three matrices you have the equation.
$$(X+C)=X^{-1}+C^{-1}$$ then as before you can solve for $CX^{-1}=D$ and let 
$C=DX$.

Comment: but I need an example of k matrices 2x2. Look at the equality.

Comment: Well I thought you were going to do a block matrix argument.